# Is there any limitations in SharePoint 2010 to make Websites with any Design and with Semantic HTML5, CSS3, jQuery?

Tags: asp.net, html, sharepoint-2010, css, content-management-system

Is there any limitations in SharePoint 2010 to make Websites with any Design and with Semantic HTML5, CSS3, jQuery?

Is there any difference to make website with *Sharepoint* compare to *wordpress* in terms of using **HTML, CSS and JavaScript, jquery** etc?

Can I just deliver HTML+CSS+jQuery template ([like this](http://www.elladesign.com/))  to Sharepoint Developer to integrate?

I need to convert a PSD into HTML+CSS+JS and I have Free Microsoft Visual Web Developer Express in my PC. Is there any difference in process to make template for Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are certain limitations. For example, the main frame in sharepoint is emitted by a component called master page, which you edit in sharepoint designer. You need sharepoint designer rather than Visual Web Developer express.

You have to tweak the master page file to achieve your desired output.

Also, certain certain UI elements in sharepoint site are web controls and hence their emiitted HTML cannot be tweaked to a certain extent. This prevents sharepoint site to be perfect XHMTL or any compliance standard.

See:

http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2007/10/08/sharepoint-branding-how-css-works-with-master-pages-part-1/

Comment: I've made some asp.net templates using nested master pages in Visual web developer express following this http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/09/vs-2008-nested-master-page-support.aspx. and I also used CSS friendly adapter in that http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/ but it was 2 yrs ago. Now I need to convert a PSD 2 Sharepoint 2010

Comment: Can I sharepoint 2010 expert Integrate my HTML/CSS template into Sharepoint template?

Comment: Yes, a expert can integrate with some effort

Answer (score 0):

I have found by experimenting that there are LIMITATIONS in using HTML5 tags in Sharepoint 2010 Content Editor Web Parts. Apparently Sharepoint intervenes and modifies the html. I unfortunately do not know how to overcome this (yet), but surely the answer to your question is Yes.